# Storing array as map values problem

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, perl-data-structures

I want `@arr` to directly contain the cities name. I want `$arr[0]` to be `c1` when I print.
What is wrong with the code?

```
my $state="Illinois";

 push @{$mstates{$state}}, "c1";

 push @{$mstates{$state}}, "c2";


 my @arr=$mstates{$state};
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you wanted

```
my @arr=@{$mstates{$state}};
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like,

```
my @arr=@{$mstates{$state}};
```

ie.,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $state="Illinois";
my %mstates;
 push @{$mstates{$state}}, "c1";
 push @{$mstates{$state}}, "c2";
 my @arr=@{$mstates{$state}};
 print Dumper(\@arr);
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'c1',
          'c2'
        ];
```